# Help in identifying a mystery wall socket

Tags: connectors

I am trying to identify a mystery wall receptacle that I have in my house (built in the 60s, USA).  I have one in the living room next to a fireplace, another in a bedroom.  It looks somewhat like the C8 socket, but is more rectangular and rough-looking.

Does anybody know what this is?

EDIT: added opened picture

[image: Mystery wall connector]

[image: Opened plate]

Comment: an early phone socket? or for a speaker?

Comment: A duplicate of this question, I believe:
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29430/what-type-of-outlet-is-in-the-picture

Comment: As the flat wire is now exposed it is a tv antennae connection and this is a duplicate of the other question

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think this is indeed the same socket as the other question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for providing the "opened" picture, which clearly reveals that this is 300 ohm TV (and/or FM radio) antenna twinlead.

Not quite as obsolete as a buggywhip, but pretty close.

Comment: +1 for "twinlead". That was indeed the type of antenna lead wires.

Comment: Are HD antennas not roof mounted, and signal over this wire?

Comment: The original TV antennas this stuff was common for *still work with HDTV* if you have them (you don't actually need a "HDTV Antenna"), but most modern antennas use a 75 ohm coaxial feed rather than twinlead. It's shielded by design, which reduces interference pickup. It's also a LOT easier to find hardware for, these days.